# Entity FrameWork System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: entity-framework, datetime

my project use ef and reposiroty for communication with database

when i find a record with the id

```
 var applicant = applicantProvider.Get(1020);    

 Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
```

then i got exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

the data record is :

id        DOB                 SubmitDate CreateDate UpdateDate

1020    01/06/1949  2010-05-12 16:01:39 2010-05-14 16:59:10 2011-05-28 10:22:00

i don't know how i got that error pls help me

My entity Applicant

```
public class ABGApplicant

public int ABGApplicantID { get; set; }
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
public DateTime? SubmitDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? UpdateDate{ get; set; }
```

this is my main function

```
IABGApplicantProvider applicantProvider = new ABGApplicantProvider(new GenesisContext());

            var applicant = applicantProvider.Get(1020);
```

this is my ABGApplicantProvider  extend repository

```
public class ABGApplicantProvider : Repository<ABGApplicant>, IABGApplicantProvider
    {
        public ABGApplicantProvider(DbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is class Repository

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class

public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            // Here we are working with a DbContext, not PlutoContext. So we don't have DbSets 
            // such as Courses or Authors, and we need to use the generic Set() method to access them.
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: is possible you're passing not an int or string or guid but a Datetime in your function Find(id)..so your id is a datetime?

Comment: No my id is number just want to find by id 
 var applicant = applicantProvider.Get(1020);

Comment: can you post your POCO? your TEntity

Comment: i Updated my question

Comment: ok ..i'm pretty sure you've a dirty record in your db .. in the field maybe DOB ..can you check on Db ..in the record with id=1020 ..if is there something strange?

Comment: oh you right oh my god i thought the field DOB is Datetime Type but that field is nvarchar thank you

Comment: i post as an answer..if you want rate it..so maybe if other people need it it can help them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not in your repository but in the data inside your DB...

Check the record with `id=1020` and then check the `column DOB`